# Why doesn't the Rails migration generator respect the fields I ask for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-generate

I use the command like this:

```
administrator@ubuntu:~/demo$ rails generate migration Testabc test123:string
```

and the terminal respond:

```
invoke active_record
create db/migrate/20120204124219_testabc.rb
```

But in the file`s content is:

```
class Testabc < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

So, where is my table and the string column?

Answer (score 3):

Your migration needs to look like `rails g migration add_<field>_to_<table> field:type`. For example, this:

```
rails generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string
```

will produce this:

```
class AddFieldnameToTablename < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :tablenames, :fieldname, :string
  end

  def down
    remove_column :tablenames, :fieldname
  end
end
```

If you wanted to generate a *model* from scratch, then you should do:

```
rails generate model Widget fieldname:string
```

which will produce a migration that includes the fields needed for the model.

Comment: At first,I just want to create a middle table to connect two tables,build a many-to-many relationship.
This is just a simple example,I do not intending to modify a table :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for:

```
rails generate model Testabc test123:string
```